# SQL query involving tables having many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, many-to-many

In the application I am developing, search criteria entered by users, need to be saved, and to be run periodically (for example on a daily basis) so the results can be sent to the users. In addition, in each run, the criteria record is updated to indicate the latest execution time and also the number of new results found since last time.

Search is performed against a table called Things, which has many-to-many relations with Colors and Kinds tables, using ThingColors and ThingKinds relation tables, respectively. Each Thing must be associated with at least one Color and one Kind, and it must have a Name and a Rate.

```
Things                  Colors          Kinds           ThingColors       ThingKinds
------                  ------          -----           -----------       ----------
ThingId: int            ColorId: int    KindId: int     ThingId: int      ThingId: int
ThingName: varchar      Name: varchar   Name: varchar   ColorId: int      KindId: int
Description: varchar
Rate: int
AddedOn: datetime
```

The table for saved criteria looks like the following. Criteria has also many-to-many relations with Colors and Kinds. None of the search criteria (MinRate, MaxRate, Color, and Kind) are mandatory, but at lease one must be specified. If one or more Colors are specified in the search criteria, there must be at least one matching Color in a Thing so it can be included in the results. The same type of condition applies to Kind.

```
Criteria                    CriteriaColors         CriteriaKinds
--------                    --------------         -------------
CriteriaId: int             CriteriaId: int        CriteriaId: int
UserId: int                 ColorId: int           KindId: int
CriteriaName: varchar
MinRate: int
MaxRate: int
NewResults: int
LatestRanOn: datetime
```

I am looking for an efficient query to generate the results (list of matched Things against each criteria). Is there a way to update the Criteria with the number of newly found matches (Things that have AddedOn after LatestRanOn of Criteria), and also updating LatestRanOn, within the same query?

Currently I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Please show some things you have tried.

Comment: And give an example of the output you want.  The simple answer to our last question is that you can't update two tables within a single `update` statement.  Do you really mean update?